# Raising event in UserControl Class

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, user-controls

So, I have a UserControl where I have a handle for button click:

`Private Sub Forward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Forward.Click`

and a second button click:

`Private Sub back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Back.Click`

I have another handle for a mouse click on the userControl:

`Private Sub UserControl_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick`

Depending on the condition, I want to raise event of one of the button clicks from this sub function. All these handles are in the same UserControl Class. How would it be implementable.

Comment: It looks like you don't want to *raise an event*, but to execute the code that's inside the `Button.Click` handler.

Comment: @Jimi, you are correct but I have edited the question to stress that one of the two `Button.Click` event has to be raised from `me.MouseClick` event.

Comment: You don't need to raise the event, you need to run that code. Move the code to a private method (`Sub`) and call that method from both handlers.

Comment: @Jimi, its implementable but causes repition of code mulitple times which is not a good coding practice.

Comment: ??? You have just one method, called by other code that needs it. No *repetitions*. What you're trying to do is not *good practice*.

Comment: @Jimi, Two different button events, which need to copied to another `sub`. So if each event had 50 lines of code, I would be adding 100 lines of code extra as repitition.

Comment: You don't have to **copy** the code, you have to **move** it. Then call the method you have pasted that code in from everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for which button was clicked by comparing e.Button to MouseButton.Left or MouseButton.Right.  This would make sure that you only run code when the left mouse button was clicked.

```
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        'Any user code here
    End If
```

You can call another event handler by using its method name just like calling any other method.

```
Forward_Click(Me, Nothing)
```

To put it all together it would look something like this.

```
    Private Sub UserControl1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Forward_Click(Me, Nothing)
    ElseIf e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
        Back_Click(Me, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
```

Your conditions may be different as this is just an example.  It also may not be "Best Practice" but I am not here to argue what "Best Practice" is.  This is a working example to answer your question.  Hope it helps.